# Why does matplotlib choose the wrong range in y using log scale?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Using matplotlib version 1.5.1 and python 2.7.11 I noticed that I need to specify the limits in y manually or else only the largest y-value point is plotted. Arrays behave the same way.

If I remove the first point, I get a few more points, but not all of them.

I don't recall ever having to manually set limits like this before - why here?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [0.997, 2.643, 0.354, 0.075, 1.0, 0.03, 2.39, 0.364, 0.221, 0.437]
Y = [15.487507, 2.320735, 0.085742, 0.303032, 1.0, 0.025435, 4.436435,
     0.025435, 0.000503, 2.320735]

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')


plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim(0.5*min(Y), 2.0*max(Y))  # why is this line necessary?
plt.title('added plt.ylim()')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises because you have first drawn the scatter plot and then set the scales as logarithmic which results in a zooming in effect. This removes the problem:

```
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.scatter(X, Y)
```

This produces the intended result. (2nd subplot in your question.)

Comment: OK that's a fix, but is that the way it's supposed to work? It only affects the y scale, the x scale does not need this.

Comment: I guess I must have always been doing it in the 'right' order without realizing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `matplotlib` is creating the y-axis ticks before converting to a log scale, and then not recreating the ticks based on the change. The y-axis on your first subplot starts at 10e1, not 10e-3. So change the scales before you plot.

```
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.scatter(X, Y)
```

I think if you plot the original scale beside the log scale, you might be able to figure out the answer to the partial treatment of the axes by `matplotlib`. In a log scale, there is no true 0 -- because log(0) is undefined. So the coordinate has to start somewhere above 0, and that causes the problems. Your x axis ranges from 0 to 3, but y from 0 to 16. When converted to log, `matplotlib` correctly scales x axis, but since y has a factor of 10, it misses the scaling.

Comment: y, but not x? I use log constantly, sometimes x, or y, or both axes. I've never seen this happen before.

Comment: hmm... like I said in the other answer, possibly I've always been doing it in that order without actually realizing that it was the 'right' order.

Comment: Thanks! I looked back at some examples of my plots and I found that 90% of the time I use `plt.plot()` where the 'wrong' order works just fine. It seems it's 'wrong' for `plt.scatter()`. A lot of my scatter plots that use log scales seemed to have worked 'by accident' due to limited range - like [this one](http://pastebin.com/gQBueJVL) just for a random example. And possibly this has happened occasionally before and I just fiddled with it, got it working, and moved on.

Comment: I've linked your helpful answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38800189/3904031).